# calling smart contract function from React

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, react, smart-contract-wallets

I am calling smart contract function in Solidity from React, which should count the votes for the specific choices. The function works perfectly when I call it from my truffle console. However, when I call it from React application, the function is executed but votes are not counted.

function:

```
 function doVote(uint _choice)
        public
        inState(State.Voting)
        returns(bool voted)
    {
        bool found = false;        
        
        if(!voterRegister[msg.sender].voted ){
            voterRegister[msg.sender].voted = true;
            vote memory v;
            v.voterAddress = msg.sender;
            v.choice = _choice;

            
            candidatesRegister[_choice].votes++  ;
            
            votes[totalVote] = v;
            totalVote++;
            found = true;
        }
        return found;        
    }
```

in truffle console, this works:

```
> ballot = await Ballot.deployed()
> ballot.doVote(1)
```

In React I have this function where the address represents the public key of a user being logged in to the application:

```
export const doVote = async (choice, address)=> {
 

    web3.eth.defaultAccount = address;
    console.log("network: " + Contract.networks[networkID].address)
    const BallotContract = new web3.eth.Contract(Contract.abi, Contract.networks[networkID].address);       

    return await BallotContract.methods
    .doVote(choice)

};
```

if I add .call() to .doVote(choice) function will return "true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is with ethers assuming that you have metamask in your browser:

I also used react, I stored the contract abi in a json as well as the address

```
import smartContract from './smart-contract-abi.json';
import contractAddress from './contract-address.json';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';

// step 1 - Connect wallet

await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});

// step 2 - Initialize your contract

    this.provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    this.yourSignedContractObject = new ethers.Contract(
      contractAddress.Address, 
      smartContract.Abi,
      this.provider.getSigner(0)
    );

// step 3 - Submit transaction to metamask

    const tx = await this.yourSignedContractObject.doVote(yourChoice)
```

Source: (check the typescript PR)
https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat-boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing [.call()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call), the blockchain's state is not altered. According to the web3 docs:

```
methods.myMethod.call

Will call a “constant” method and execute its smart contract method in the EVM without sending any transaction. Note calling cannot alter the smart contract state.
```

Call is useful for simulating a transaction and getting its return value, which you got as "true", but because the blockchain's state isn't changed, your votes aren't counted.

What you really want to do is use [.send()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send)

```
methods.myMethod.send
Will send a transaction to the smart contract and execute its method. Note this can alter the smart contract state.
```