# How do I set the transaction msg.value to 1 ether?

Tags: solidity, remix, dapps, erc-721, python

The problem is that when I am clicking a button using the safeMint function, I do not know how to input a value for the cost to mint. So I am essentially minting with air. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX2kf.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuFo7.png)

I have included a mintRate and a require statement to make sure that the transaction has to be at least 1 ether, but in my application I do not know how to include a price. I works without a price but I would like to include a price to mint. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFEdo.png)

This is the code for what I have so far i just need to make it have a value of 1 ether for minting the nft.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JheAp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is not very clear but what I understand is that you want to do this:

1.- create a token that can be minted for 1ETH, to do this you must set the price on contract level by checking the value of a transaction

```
function mint(uint256 id, uint256 amount) external payable {
  require(msg.value == 1000000000000000000, "invalid paid amount");
  _safeMint(id,amount);
}
```

note of the code:
1000000000000000000wei == 1eth

2.- Send a transaction with 1eth

I usually do something like this to have a bit more control:

```
uint256 price;

function setPrice(uint256 foo) external onlyOwner{
  price = foo;
}

function mint(uint256 id, uint256 amount) external payable {
  require(msg.value == price, "invalid paid amount");
  _safeMint(id,amount);
}
```

Now you should be able to call the mint function and you now must input some eth in there.. Example call in typescript + truffle:

```
it("Should succed - mints a token with 1eth fee",async () =>{
  const price = ethers.utils.parseEther("1")
  expect(await yourContract.mint(1, 1, {value: price})).to.be.ok
})
```

Example function in Python with brownie:

```
from brownie import yourContract, accounts, config
from web3 import Web3
mintAmount = 2
payable = mintAmount * 0.01

def mint():
    dev = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])

    # Get the latest deployed contract
    yourContract = contract[len(contract) - 1]
   
    yourContract.mint(
        mintAmount, {"from": dev, "value": Web3.toWei(payable, "ether")}
    )
```

If you want to add value in the FE ie react you need to do something like this, more info on how to input value [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/111663/99976) and how to initialize contracts in React + metamask [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/134779/99976):

```
yourContract.mint(1,1, { value: price });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you testing in remix you can change your input from wei to eth ,then input 1 eth or any value that you want .

another way is input as a wei, `1 ether == 10 ** 18 wei`

so if you want to set your input as a wei you need 1 and 18 zero 's:

```
1000000000000000000
```

and also you can use web3js documentation if want to deploy your contract in vsCode or ...

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#fromwei